# Parsing variable from HTML/JS to Python with Flask always returns None

Tags: python, html, json, flask, deployment

I'm trying to parse a string variable, "articlename" to my main Flask Python script from HTML (with JS). However, all it returns is None. How can I fix this?

HTML/JS:

```
    <p>
        <button id="likebutton" onclick="likePost()">
            <img class="likebuttonimg" src="static/images/clearlike.png" id = image>
        </button>
    </p>
    <p>
    {{likes}} likes
    {{views}} views
    </p>

    <script>
        let data = new FormData()
        data.append("name", "sketchystrats")

        document.getElementById("likebutton").onclick = function () {
            fetch('/tracklikes', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'name': 'sketchystrats'},
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            })
        };
    </script>
```

Relevant section of Python:

```
@app.route("/tracklikes", methods=['POST'])
def tracklikes():
    print("TrackLikes activated")
    articlename = request.form.get('data')
    print(str(articlename))
```

Then it does some database stuff that isn't super relevant. For note, I don't know what I'm doing when it comes to Javascript.

Comment: If I read your code correctly, you aren't returning anything in ```def tracklikes():```.  Aren't you supposed to return something like ```return str(articlename)```?  But since the javascript is expecting some sort of JSON, I would think something like ```return {"articlename": str(articlename)}```?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear - I'm not returning anything to JS, all it does is send data to python/flask. The intention of this script is ONLY to send the string "articlename" from JS to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must decide whether you want to send JSON format or form data.
Your endpoint expects a form, so remove `JSON.stringify(...)` and send the FormData object directly. Specifying the header is also not necessary.

```js
let data = new FormData()
data.append('name', 'sketchystrats')

document.getElementById('likebutton').onclick = function () {
    fetch('/tracklikes', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data,
    });
};
```

On the server side, the input must be queried based on the name under which you added the data to the FormData object. In your case this corresponds to `name`, not `data`.
Don't forget that an endpoint requires a return value, otherwise an error will be thrown.

```py
@app.post('/tracklikes')
def tracklikes():
    articlename = request.form.get('name')
    print(articlename)
    return ''
```